# Pyglet draws both windows on same screen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, display, pyglet

I'm running a project on a Raspberry Pi, wanting to draw a countdown timer on one screen and a progress bar of sorts on the other. Windows are being created with pyglet.
I've tried the following code:

```
import pyglet
display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
screens = display.get_screens()
screen1, screen2 = screens
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True, screen=screen1)
window2 = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True, screen=screen2)
```

Printing the screens array in my IDE's shell shows that there are two screens with different x positions (as intended) but when I run the code both windows are opened on top of each other onthe same screen.
Any suggestions?